# Need help with MVC-pattern

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have just started to read about the MVC pattern and I do not understand it completely.

> The model manages the behavior and
>   data of the application domain,
>   responds to requests for information
>   about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to
>   change state (usually from the
>   controller). In event-driven systems,
>   the model notifies observers (usually
>   views) when the information changes so
>   that they can react.
>
> The view renders the model into a form
>   suitable for interaction, typically a
>   user interface element. Multiple views
>   can exist for a single model for
>   different purposes. A viewport
>   typically has a one to one
>   correspondence with a display surface
>   and knows how to render to it.
>
> The controller receives user input and
>   initiates a response by making calls
>   on model objects. A controller accepts
>   input from the user and instructs the
>   model and viewport to perform actions
>   based on that input.

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

And

> Model. The model manages the behavior
>   and data of the application domain,
>   responds to requests for information
>   about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to
>   change state (usually from the
>   controller).
>
> View. The view manages the display of
>   information.
>
> Controller. The controller interprets
>   the mouse and keyboard inputs from the
>   user, informing the model and/or the
>   view to change as appropriate.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx)

I think I understand what the Model and View are however I do not understand the controller. From the text that I read and some examples I have seen the controller takes input from the user. I have seen examples such as (in Java): The controller is a JOptionPane that receives a number in fahrenheit from the user. Then assign and convert it in the model and shows the result in the command line. I do not understand why the controller takes input like that?

In Ruby on Rails I have the model that stores the data, the controller that displays different views and do "stuff" on the input that was received in the View.

Comment: +1 @Niko : Good qn. Your last sentence, about how you understand the controller in RoR, is spot on for other languages as well.

Comment: @bguiz: Thank you. So is that correct? That the controller displays an appropriate view, the user interacts with the view maybe filling in some data in forms, then press submit and this data is processed and inserted into the model by the code in the controller?

Comment: Your last sentence sums it up very good. I understand it the same way. Can you point us to the example you're struggling with?

Comment: das_weezul: I got no particular example that I struggle with, I just have some trouble understanding the concept correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply,

The View - is responsible for drawing or rendering the information from the Model

The Model - is responsible for your business logic, and storing the state of your application

The Controller - is reponsible for interpreting the user's actions and invoking the necessary events on the Model and informing the View to update itself (if required).

The View should only be responsible for drawing/rendering, so it should not know about what events should occur on a user's interaction. The Model should only be interested in business logic and data. It should not know anything about the View. The controller therefore ties these two pieces together, allowing for the Model to be re-usable and to enable Multiple Views over a single Model (think mobile / TV / Web view of the same data model).

In a Web world, your Controller is the piece that receives your HTTP inputs, your View is your HTML/JSP code and your Controller is the Servlet (or framework equivalent) that acts on the HTTP request to perform the necessary business in the model.

Comment: Thank you, made it a bit clearer but I do not see in the answer above where the userinput fits in (not web world).

Comment: user inputs are handled by the controller. In a desktop world, this would be your JComponent, such as JTextPane, the UI is handled by the JTextPaneUI and the model is the StyledDocument.

Answer (score 0):

As the name *controller* indicates already, the controller interprets the input and coordinates/controls communication between the model and the views, i.e. it would first trigger the model update and then (if the views don't directly observe the model) notify the views of the model change so that they can update themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a very basic application: one model (a Java bean) that reflects a database table, a dialog with labels and textfields to display all values and a magic button to refresh the content.

The controller now has the logic to update the textfields with new values *after* the user has clicked on (aka *pressed the*) the button widget.

In this simple case:

```
 Model:      Java bean (fields, getters, setters)
 View:       frame with txtfields, labels and a button widget
 Controller: logic to tell the model to update itself, update the textfields and tell 
             the view to refresh
```

User input in textfields - if you have databinding, then the databinding itself is a controller's responsibility. Because databinding sends update signals to model and view. If your application does not use databinding, then the model update triggered by an action (button click) or some event (focus change, ...). And this logic is part of the controller again.

BTW: *The view and controller implement the classic Strategy Pattern: the vew is an object that is configured with a strategy* (Head First Design Patterns, p. 532)

Comment: Thank you, I think I start to understand it. The view is just the container and boxes and it is the controller job to fetch whatever content that is in this boxes when some userinteraction happens, such as when the user hit a button?

Comment: @Niko Aralo - That's my understanding of MVC (and that it's sometimes difficult, complicated and often unnecessary to strictly separate view from controller...)

Answer (score 0):

The controller basically takes a user interaction and, using some kind of mapping, it will initiates a response by calling the model. The model will have the business logic for data manipulation. Once the controller has the response from the model, the controller will pass the model to the view will render an interface for viewing and user interaction (based on the model).

> In Ruby on Rails I have the model that
>   stores the data, the controller that
>   displays different views and do
>   "stuff" on the input that was received
>   in the View.

Model is fine, the controller must be responsible for user interaction and the view for the rendering of the model to a UI.

Answer (score 0):

The input field (e.g. JTextField) is part of the View, the logic determining what to do on what interaction events (typing a character, loosing focus, clicking a button ...) is in the Controller.

Like in your example, the logic of the Controller **COULD** be in the same class as the View. This would be the case if you extend JOptionPane and also implement the ActionListener so that the JOptionPane can react to events of the JTextField. **BUT** this is clearly discouraged if you want to establish a clear MVC pattern, as you would mix code of the View and the Controller.